# regex from char to char select an interval delimited by chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, text-parsing

I have a string in JavaScript/JQuery and I want to replace only the value not in HTML tags:

```
< div class="myClass contentTab" id="myId">
  this is my content and I will work only on this 
</div>
```

I want to replace the word content, but not the word in the HTML tag, with `<b> + content + </b>`. result should be like:

```
< div class="myClass contentTab" id="myId">
  this is my <b>content</b> and I will work only on this 
</div>
```

The class of the div `contentTab` shuld not be replaced, rather the word "content" should be replaced.

Comment: regex is not the right tool for parsing HTML, and `<b>` is not the right HTML to be using.

Comment: i did not specify, i have to work with the string. i don't have html i have the string: "< div class=\"myClass contentTab\" id=\"myId\">
  this is my content and I will work only on this 
</div>" so it can't be handled using dom...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the below code:

```
var temp = "<div class='myClass contentTab'id='myId'>  this is my content and I will   work only on this </div>";
$('body').append($(temp));
var req = temp.match(/>(.*?)</g);
var beforeresult = temp.match(/>(.*?)</g);
var afterresult = beforeresult[0].replace("content","<b>content</b>");
var aftertemp = temp.replace(beforeresult,afterresult);
$('body').append($(aftertemp));
```

Refer to this fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jk86/14/)

Comment: abstract to a function: `function addtag(str, el, tag) { return str.replace(el, "<" + tag + ">" + el + "</" + tag + ">"); }`  `addtag($("#myId").html(), "content", "strong");`

Comment: i can't use $(div) because i have to work with the entire string: "< div class=\"myClass contentTab\" id=\"myId\">
  this is my content and I will work only on this 
</div>" can you suggest something else? :)

Comment: Wow this is like magic! i still have to fully understand javascript and regex interaction anyway thanks this works! :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best solution is to declare a `<span />` element where the text should be replaced.

You can see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A8k5T/) of this

In short, I added a `<span>` tag inside the text of the container and a text input.

```
<div class="myClass contentTab" id="myId">
  this is my <span id = 'text_replace'>content</span> and I will work only on this 
</div>

<input type = "text" id = "text_input" />
<button id = 'replacement'>Replace Text</button>
```

Using jQuery, I declared two event listeners, and the end result is the span element text is replaced with whatever content you want.

```
$("#text_input").on("click", function(){
  var text = $("#text_replace").text();
  $(this).val(text);
});

$("#replacement").click(function(){
  var inputVal = $("#text_input").val(); 
  $("#text_replace").text(inputVal);
});
```

Should you want to add bold text as in your original example, then using `.css("font-weight", "bold")` will work as well.